# SSHD with Win8.1: Write caching necessary for performance improvements?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, ssd

I bought a new laptop with a SSHD drive. I usually disable write caching on all my HDDs. Will disabling write caching prevent the SSHD from reaching its full potential?

I tried copying some folders with it enabled / disabled and didn't notice and improvement in performance, but then again, these folders where probably not in the SSD part of the SSHD anyway.

Is write caching recommended / necessary to make full use of my SSHD?

Answer (score 0):

Even though a SSD is faster than a magnetic HD, RAM is faster yet. My inclination would be to allow write caching for two reasons:

1. It should be faster than actually writing to the SSD.
2. There should be less wear on the SSD, which has a finite number of writes available. That said, [SSD's can write *terabytes* of data before failure](http://techreport.com/review/27909/the-ssd-endurance-experiment-theyre-all-dead).

One reason to turn off write caching is where frequent crashes are expected, as in a programming environment. In C++ development, I lost changes to programs that caused BSD, until I shut caching.